# Unable to get Response from Redux action using Mocha Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, mocha.js, react-redux, enzyme

I am using Enzyme to unit test my React components. In my use case I want to validate login by setting state value and after simulating click event we must be able to get response from action.

**Container**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { authenticate } from './actions';
import LoginForm from './LoginForm';


 class Login extends Component {
  state = {
    redirect: false
  }

  showData = () => {
    console.log("in showData method");
  }

  login = ({ email, password }) => {
     console.log("called2");
     var self = this;

    return this.props.authenticate({ email, password })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {
          this.state.redirect ?
          <Redirect to="/posts" /> :
          <LoginForm login={this.login} />
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state, props) {
  console.log("called");
  return {};
}

 export default connect(mapStateToProps, { authenticate })(Login);
```

**Component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

function setErrorMsg(error) {
  return {
    loginMessage: error
  }
}

export default class LoginForm extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);    
      this.state = {
        email: "",
        password :"",
       loginMessage: null
      }
      this.updateEmailState = this.updateEmailState.bind(this);
      this.updatePasswordState = this.updatePasswordState.bind(this);
      this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
   }

  handleSubmit() {
    //e.preventDefault()


    try{
    console.log(this.state);  
    const { email, password } = this.state;
    this.props.login({ email, password })

    }catch(ex){
      console.log(ex)
      console.log("called");
    }
  }

  resetPassword = () => {
    // resetPassword(this.email.value)
    //   .then(() => this.setState(setErrorMsg(`Password reset email sent to ${this.email.value}.`)))
    //   .catch((error) => this.setState(setErrorMsg(`Email address not found.`)))
  }

  updateEmailState(e) {
      this.setState({email: e.target.value});
   }

  updatePasswordState(e) {
      this.setState({password: e.target.value});
   }

  render () {
    return (
      <div className="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
        <h1> Login </h1>
        <form >
          <div className="form-group">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input  className="form-control email"value={this.state.email} 
               onChange={this.updateEmailState}  placeholder="Email"/>
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password" className="form-control password"
             value={this.state.password} 
               onChange={this.updatePasswordState} 
             placeholder="Password" />
          </div>
          {
            this.state.loginMessage &&
            <div className="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
              <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span className="sr-only">Error:</span>
              &nbsp;{this.state.loginMessage} 
            </div>
          }

        </form>
        <button type="button" onClick={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)} className="btn btn-primary loginbtn">Login</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

LoginForm.propTypes = {
  email: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired ,
  password: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired 
};

LoginForm.defaultProps = {
  email: "",
  password :"" 
}
```

**Action**

```
export const SET_TASKS = 'SET_TASKS';
export const ADD_TASK = 'ADD_TASK';
export const TASK_FETCHED = 'TASK_FETCHED';
export const TASK_UPDATED = 'TASK_UPDATED';
export const TASK_DELETED = 'TASK_DELETED';
export const LOGGEDIN = 'LOGGEDIN';
export const LOGIN = 'LOGIN';
require('es6-promise').polyfill();
require('isomorphic-fetch');

function handleResponse(response) {
  if (response.ok) {
    return response.json();
  } else {
    let error = new Error(response.statusText);
    error.response = response;
    throw error;
  }
}


export function loggedIn(user, token) {
  console.log("user = " + user + " token = " + token)
   user.token = token
   user.isAuthenticated = true
   return {
      type: LOGGEDIN,
      user
   }
}

export function authenticate(data) {
  console.log(data);
  return dispatch => {
    return fetch("/api/login", {
      method: 'post',
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    }).then(handleResponse)
    .then(data => dispatch(loggedIn(data.user, data.token)));
  }
}

export const LOGOUT = 'LOGOUT';
export function logout() {
   return {
      type: LOGOUT
   }
}

export function logoutUser(data) {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(logout())
  }
}

export function settasks(tasks) {
  return {
    type: SET_TASKS,
    tasks
  }
}

export function addtask(task) {
  return {
    type: ADD_TASK,
    task
  }
}

export function taskFetched(task) {
  return {
    type: TASK_FETCHED,
    task
  }
}

export function taskUpdated(task) {
  return {
    type: TASK_UPDATED,
    task
  }
}

export function taskDeleted(taskId) {
  return {
    type: TASK_DELETED,
    taskId
  }
}

export function savetask(data) {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    const { user } = getState();
    return fetch('/api/tasks', {
      method: 'post',
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "x-access-token": user.token
      }
    }).then(handleResponse)
    .then(data => dispatch(addtask(data.task)));
  };
}

export function updatetask(data) {
  return dispatch => {
    return fetch(`/api/tasks/${data._id}`, {
      method: 'put',
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    }).then(handleResponse)
    .then(data => dispatch(taskUpdated(data.task)));
  }
}

export function deletetask(id) {
  return dispatch => {
    return fetch(`/api/tasks/${id}`, {
      method: 'delete',
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    }).then(handleResponse)
    .then(data => dispatch(taskDeleted(id)));
  }
}

export function fetchtasks() {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    const { user } = getState();
    fetch('/api/tasks', {
      headers: {
        "x-access-token": user.token
      }
    }).then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => dispatch(settasks(data.tasks)));

  };
}

export function fetchtask(id) {
  return dispatch => {
    fetch(`/api/tasks/${id}`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => dispatch(taskFetched(data.task)));
  }
}
```

**Test**

```
import React from 'react';
import {findDOMNode} from 'react-dom';
import { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme';
import chai from 'chai';
import  LoginForm  from '../LoginForm';
import TestUtils from 'react-addons-test-utils';
import configureMockStore  from 'redux-mock-store';
import  Login  from '../Login';
//import App from '../App';
import sinon from 'sinon';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
const wrapper = shallow(<LoginForm />)
//const wrapper_app = shallow(<App />)
const wrapper_mount = mount(<LoginForm />)
const middlewares = [ thunk ]
const mockStore = configureMockStore(middlewares)
chai.config.includeStack = true;
global.chai = chai;
global.AssertionError = chai.AssertionError;
global.Assertion = chai.Assertion;
global.expect = chai.expect;
global.assert = chai.assert;


describe('Login Test', () => {

  it('click login', (done) => {
    const login = sinon.spy();
    const wrapperData = mount(<Login login={login} store={mockStore()} />)

    wrapperData.find(LoginForm).find('.email').simulate('change', {target: {value: 'test'}});
    wrapperData.find(LoginForm).find('.password').simulate('change', {target: {value: '12345'}});
    wrapperData.find(LoginForm).find('button').simulate('click')


    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          resolve();
      });

    return promise.then(() => {

      setTimeout(function(){
           console.log('waiting over.');
          expect(true).to.be.true // successful
          console.log(wrapperData.state('redirect'))  // prints undefined
           done();
       }, 5000)

      }).catch(function(error) {  
        console.log('Request failed', error)  
      });

  });
});
```

**Getting Output as**

[See Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1xNx.png)

Comment: Please don't include text as a screenshot. Include any text you want in the question itself.

Comment: @BSMP sure will take care of it

Comment: Do you have any inputs for my question.